# Insert com dois selects diferentes

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

Esse meu `insert` não está funcionando.

```
insert into t_cmo_oit1980 (id_oit, id_exm_rea) 
    select max(id_oit) + 1 from t_cmo_oit1980,
    select id_exm_rea from t_cmo_Exame_Realizado where id_exm = 3936 and id_xfc = 39517;
    go
```

Fiz uma gambi e gerei na mão o valor do primeiro campo e mesmo assim não funcionou. Fiz assim:

```
insert into t_cmo_oit1980 (id_oit, id_exm_rea) 
    6574,
    select id_exm_rea from t_cmo_Exame_Realizado where id_exm = 3936 and id_xfc = 39517;
    go
```

Comment: Uma pergunta apenas, não sei se estou saindo do escopo, acho que não, mas quando vou inserir uma data, me dá esse erro. `Mensagem 8152, Nível 16, Estado 14, Linha 19
String or binary data would be truncated.
The statement has been terminated.`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Faltou transformar seus `sub-select` em um `select` válido para a cláusula `Values`:

```
insert into t_cmo_oit1980 (id_oit, id_exm_rea) 
    select 
      (select max(id_oit) + 1 from t_cmo_oit1980),
      (select id_exm_rea from t_cmo_Exame_Realizado where id_exm = 3936 and id_xfc = 39517);
    go
```

Referência:
[Adicionando linhas usando INSERT e SELECT](https://technet.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ms188263(v=sql.105).aspx)